# Setting different view controller for one tab

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have 5 tab in my tab bar controller. Users can use my application as anonymus user. One of my tabs is Login page. if user logged in my application, that tab should be Home page. but I don't know how set different view controller for one tab based on if condition

Comment: What issues are you facing? Please share your code so far.

Comment: like I said I don't know where check my if condition and set different view controller for one tab

Comment: I write my app with swift. I search very lot in internet but can't find any like this issue

Comment: How are you setting your controllers to TabBar i.e. through storyboard or through code ?

Comment: through storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the possible solutions is to use container view controller.
So, your view controller will have 2 embedded view controllers, and in code you can choose between them based on your logic.

There you can find some relevant examples and topics:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

[iOS Switching an embedded view in storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483992/ios-switching-an-embedded-view-in-storyboard)

[Embed UIViewController Programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166319/embed-uiviewcontroller-programatically)